# Submitting JSR to JCP?

Tags: java, jsr

Say I want to submit the JSR where I want to request some new API or some optimization in existing API

Went through https://jcp.org/en/procedures/overview. Looks like any user can not submit JSR. It can be initiated by community members.
**Right ?**

I believe anyone can be JCP member by filling a form available at the JCP website and it is free. Once it is done, can I submit JSR for review?